# embedding .js code using openfl

Tags: javascript, haxe, openfl

I'm integrating an external JS library (timbre.js) into a Haxe / OpenFL project. Right now I'm just injecting calls to the library using the untyped keyword, like this:

```
untyped T("sin").play();
```

then I build the html5 ... but I have to insert this line manually into index.html, before the line that embeds the .js file created by openfl:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/timbre.js"></script>
```

I would have guessed that there's a way to have openfl create this line automatically by some tag in the project.xml file, but I've failed to discover a way of doing this. Or would it be something in Main.hx itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `index.html` template in your `project.xml` file.

Something like: `<template path="custom_index.html" rename="index.html" />`

The template file is here: `openfl/templates/html5/template/index.html` Copy it to your project folder and edit it.

[Here is the full documentation](http://www.openfl.org/learn/resources/command-line-tools/project-files/xml-format/) In the `Additional tags` section.

Comment: That works, thanks! In the template you directed me to, there is an iteration using a format that I don't recognize, with a lot of colons, something like `::if linkedLibraries::::foreach (linkedLibraries):: ` I suppose that might be a clue for another way to do this. But for my purposes this solution is fine.

Answer (score 0):

`<dependency />` tag is designed for this. There are three options:

1. Ship the library with your project as a separate file:

   ```xml
   <dependency path="js-libs/someLibrary.js" />
   ```

   `js-libs/someLibrary.js` file will be copied to `lib` directory of the compiled project.
2. Embed the library:

   ```xml
   <dependency path="js-libs/someLibrary.js" embed="true"/>
   ```

   The content of `js-libs/someLibrary.js` will be embedded into compiled application's `.js` file.
3. Add remote link to the library:

   ```xml
   <dependency name="https://unpkg.com/simple-peer@5.9.0/simplepeer.min.js" />
   ```

The resulted `index.html` will have an appropriate `<script>` tag.

NOTE: This is not in the Lime/OpenFl doc but there is a [PR to fix it](https://github.com/openfl/lime.openfl.org/pull/17).